# Fastest way to copy various arrays into a single larger array in C without dynamic memory allocation

Tags: arrays, c, performance, copy, stack

I was wondering what would be the fastest (or a very fast) way to combine two different arrays into one larger array. As a toy example, let us say I want to combine initialized arrays `int smallArray0[3]` and `int smallArray1[2]`.

I could instead just use, for example, a pointer via mallocs, memcpys and frees, but I am under the impression (correct me if I am wrong) that it is faster to keep everything in the stack (for smaller amounts of data). For this reason, let us not use dynamic allocation.

If I want to do an actual duplicate of the data, I can only think of declaring an `int biggerArray[5]` and using a for/while loop to populate it like so:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    biggerArray[i] = smallerArray0[i];
for (i = 3; i < 5; i++)
    biggerArray[i] = smallerArray1[i - 3];
```

Is there be a way of not having to *actually* copy the data and having some sort of pointer that sequentially points to all elements of `smallArray0` and finally to `smallArray1`? If this is possible, would this be faster?

I hope that makes sense, and if not I am happy to clarify.

Comment: Regarding copying the 2 arrays into 1 larger one, at least for any reasonable size, you should use `memcpy` instead to get better performance (note it's likely written in assembly & fully optimized). Also, regarding not copying the data but using some sort of pointer, there's an array of pointers, with the first part pointing to elements of `smallArray0` and the second part to `smallArray1`. However, I suspect this would actually be somewhat slower to set up than just copying, and certainly will take more processing power each time its used due to the extra level of indirection being used.

Comment: @JohnOmielan very unlikely to be written in assembler nowadays.

Comment: You can do the copying by `memcpy(biggerArray + 0, smallerArray0, sizeof SmallerArray); memcpy(biggerArray + sizeof SmallerArray / *biggerArray, smallerArray1, sizeof smallerArray1);`. (The compiler might optimize the `for` loops the same thing, in effect.)

Comment: @gulpr: Apple’s `memcpy` is written in assembly. Due to its frequent use, it is worth hand optimizing. I believe in some cases on certain Intel CPUs, it outperformed the hardware copy-bytes instruction.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I wrote unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the great input, I certainly learned a good amount about C and the underlying structures of arrays. It seems like `memcpy` (with or without offsets) seems to be the fastest way, especially as, at least the [glibc implementation of memcpy](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/latest/source/string/memcpy.c), can copy word-by-word rather than byte-by-byte and, as the comment by [Ludin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin) mentioned, using for loops for copying arrays frequently produce the same machine code as using memcpy (depends on the compiler of course).

Comment: Whenever you use `memcpy`, the compiler looks at how much data there is to copy and generates the most efficient code accordingly. Quite often there is no function call at all, for small amounts. "Big O" is completely irrelevant. However, the requirement of `memcpy` is that it must be able to handle misaligned data, so it is possible that in some cases a plain for loop working on aligned integers might perform better. Particularly on 64 bitters that have peculiar instructions like x86 SIMD. As you can see here https://godbolt.org/z/ohscfY97c, your code generated identical code as memcpy.

Comment: Makes sense! I'll stick to memcpy from now on :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a macro that indexes into either array depending on the index. You'll have to call it using function call syntax (parentheses) rather than indexing (square brackets).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define biggerArray(index) (*((index) < 3 ? smallerArray0 + (index) : smallerArray1 + (index) - 3))

int main(void) {
    int smallerArray0[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    int smallerArray1[2] = {3, 4};

    biggerArray(4) = 10;
    printf("%d %d\n", biggerArray(1), biggerArray(4));
}
```

The macro needs to use `*(array+index)` syntax because if you use ordinary array indexing syntax in a ternary it's not assignable.

One caveat: It won't work properly if the index has side effects, because `index` is evaluated twice in the macro expansion. You could use GCC's [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) extension to solve this by declaring a temporary variable to hold the index.

Comment: This is nice idea! However am I correct to imagine that this would not work with arrays that are passes into a function by reference (e.g. foo(int *smallerArray,0 into *smallerArray1){...} )?

Comment: It will work with either arrays or pointers.

Comment: It currently has the size of `smallerArray0` hard-coded. You can easily change that to be a macro parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In a 32-bit compiler, you can pass the reference of each element to an array, and then you can get the value of that addresses in the next.
In this way, you hold the address of each array index in the stack instead of the heap.
You should consider that if you use `gcc`, compile it with `gcc -m32`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int smallerArray0[3] = {1,2,3};
    int smallerArray1[2] = {4,5};

    int biggerArray[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        biggerArray[i] = &smallerArray0[i];

    for (int i = 3; i < 5; i++)
        biggerArray[i] = &smallerArray1[i - 3];

    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        printf("%d\n", *(int*)biggerArray[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

For 64-bit compilers, you can use `uint64_t` for `biggerArray`.
Also, I should say that this is not the fastest way. I explained how you can save your addresses on the stack instead of the heap and not copy them.
However, as you can see, addresses are 64-bit numbers, and I believe that copying numbers is better than this solution.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int smallerArray0[3] = {1,2,3};
    int smallerArray1[2] = {4,5};

    uint64_t biggerArray[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        biggerArray[i] = &smallerArray0[i];

    for (int i = 3; i < 5; i++)
        biggerArray[i] = &smallerArray1[i - 3];

    for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
        printf("%d\n", *(uint64_t *)biggerArray[j]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array in C is one big chunk of memory. If you want to combine the array you have to copy them into the new combined array.

Otherwise, you will need to create a new data structure which will hold the references to the array and their sizes and then you will have to have something which will calculate how to access the particular field. It will significantly slow down the access to the elements.

```
typedef struct
{
    int *arrays[2];
    size_t sizes[2];
}data_t;

#define ADDARRAY(dtp, arr, num) do { (dtp) -> arrays[num] = (arr); (dtp) -> sizes[num] = sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]);} while(0) 


int *elemRef(const data_t *dt, size_t elem)
{
    int *result;
    if(elem >= dt -> sizes[0]) result = &dt -> arrays[1][elem - dt -> sizes[0]]; 
    else result = &dt -> arrays[0][elem];
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr1[3] = {1,2,3};
    int arr2[5] = {10,20,30,40,50};

    data_t dt;

    ADDARRAY(&dt, arr1, 0);
    ADDARRAY(&dt, arr2, 1);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("Big array[zu] = %d\n", *elemRef(&dt, i));
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        *elemRef(&dt, i) = i * 100 + 1000;
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("Big array[zu] = %d\n", *elemRef(&dt, i));
    }

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/f59r5bfqG

You can extend it to more arrays in the set.

Comment: I see, so if I want to avoid the heap via mallocing, I'm really just left with copying via for loops?

Comment: If you want to copy use `memcpy`

Answer (score 0):

This is my take for any amount of arrays to concatenate – while it
don't care about data types, preferrably all arrays should be of the same
type or you will get some nasty alignment issues:

```c
struct array {
    void *buf;
    size_t size;
};

size_t arraycat(void *dst, struct array src[], size_t narrays) {
    size_t size = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < narrays; ++i) {
        memcpy(dst, src[i].array, src[i].size);
        dst = (char *)dst + src[i].size;
        size += src[i].size;
    }
    return size;
}
```

> If this is possible (not to copy data but still be able to access the
> union of both arrays from a single data structure), would this be faster?

Totally possible. Barmar gave a pretty nice special case for two arrays.
For more arrays the space-efficient solution would be an offset table:

```
struct union_offset {
    void *buf;
    size_t start;
    size_t size;
};

size_t union_make(
    /* normally this is the return value, but asker wanted to
       avoid dynamic allocation so output parameter instead */
    struct union_offset dst[],
    struct array src[],
    size_t narrays);

void *union_index(struct union_offset union[], size_t size, size_t offset);
```

If you have to do more other operations than just the concatenation, the
reduced data locality can mean more cache misses and thus less efficient
execution. The main advantage is pretty much conserving space.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a bit of explanation on what others answered so far.

Usually compilers implement their own version of `memcpy`because it is  part of the `C` standard.

As the question and other answers did not mention `intrinsics` and it was not even tagged with `standard C`, you could write a kind of accelerated memcpy in your code (albeit you have to look for the support on your CPU). It **might** be the case that compiler uses intrinsic functions and internally uses that instead of making the call to `memcpy` as then it can even inline it and thus eliminates any function call overhead.

Not to mention that using intrinsics is made sense if you use it to copy large buffers otherwise it costs performance on small buffer copying.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there be a way of not having to actually copy the data and having some sort of pointer that sequentially points to all elements of smallArray0 and finally to smallArray1? If this is possible, would this be faster?

I think you will easily answer yourself.  Is there an efficient way to do something without actually doing it?  Would it be more efficient to walk without actually moving?

If you don't want to actually copy the data, then the best way is to avoid copying it (or at least as much as you can).  But I think this leaves the question open, as you finally don't get something you ask in your question (how to get a copy without actually copying)

Some time ago, I wrote a String object (sorry, it was C++, not c) that used COW semantics (copy on write) and slices to hold multiple copies over a common, shared buffer. (multiple string values using the same memmory) The reason was that the target processor was so memory limited that the thing sounded ok (and it worked!!!).  I got very good performance, as only on updates to the string, one of the users of that buffer (the underlying buffer of data that holded all the strings) departed by actually making the copy.  This can report a lot of savings for example on string handling (this was the use of it), as strings are far more read than written to.  But I have a question for you... do you have actually a problem with memory copying?  is that a bottleneck for your project?  If not, don't add unnecessary complexity to your code.  The implementation I used had to cope with small structures that pointed to a common, shared object that carried the number of references pointing to it (to free the buffer once the memory was not needed) and I had constructors and destructors to avoid running into trouble with dynamic memory allocation, which are not available in C.  I will ask it again: Do you have a real problem with your memory or not?  If so, please publish your code and let's see it.